# How to create InputDStream with offsets in PySpark (using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark

How to use `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` with the offsets for a particular `Topic` in Pyspark?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to create an RDD from records in a Kafka topic, use a static set of tuples.

Make available all the imports

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, OffsetRange
```

Then you create a dictionary of Kafka Brokers

```
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092"}
```

Then you create your offsets object

```
start = 0
until = 10
partition = 0
topic = 'topic'    
offset = OffsetRange(topic,partition,start,until)
offsets = [offset]
```

Finally you create the RDD:

```
kafkaRDD = KafkaUtils.createRDD(sc, kafkaParams,offsets)
```

---

To create Stream with offsets you need to do the following:

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
```

Then you create your sparkstreaming context using your sparkcontext

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
```

Next we set up all of our parameters

```
 kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "host1:9092,host2:9092,host3:9092"}
 start = 0
 partition = 0
 topic = 'topic'
```

Then we create our fromOffset Dictionary

```
topicPartion = TopicAndPartition(topic,partition)
fromOffset = {topicPartion: long(start)}
//notice that we must cast the int to long
```

Finally we create the Stream

```
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic],kafkaParams, 
fromOffsets=fromOffset)
```

Comment: but I get error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'TopicAndPartition'"

Comment: This is out of date for Kafka 0.8 and Spark 2.0+ :(

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import TopicAndPartition
topic = "test"
brokers = "localhost:9092"
partition = 0
start = 0
topicpartion = TopicAndPartition(topic, partition)
fromoffset = {topicpartion: int(start)}
kafkaDStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(spark_streaming,[topic], \
        {"metadata.broker.list": brokers}, fromOffsets = fromoffset)
```

Note: Spark 2.2.0, python 3.6